# using os.environ to tally and display lists

Tags: python, list, environment-variables, maya

Pardon me if my title misleads you but I am having problems in trying to get a list generated accordingly to the category selected and while I can change the category, it is still retaining the values of the list in the previous category selection

```
category = os.environ['CAT']
item = os.environ['ITEM']

""" ezygate.Job.getItems is the code of the inhouse tool i'm using to derive the list of items """
itemList = ezygate.job.getItems({'Items': '%s'%category})

category = ['Shirts'] 
itemList = ['v-neck', 'round', 'long sleeve', ...]
```

So when users wanted to change the category, they have to access another ui to change it (Not part of this coding), though the `os.environ['CAT']` will be updated accordingly, the itemList is wrong... For example:

```
category = ['Shorts']
itemList = ['v-neck', 'round', 'long sleeve', ...]
```

When I tried to do a `os.environ.clear()`, it screws up my Maya and I have gotten the following error:

```
# Error: CAT
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 2, in <module>
#   File "/apps/Linux64/aw/maya2014/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
#     raise KeyError(key)
# KeyError: 'CAT #
```

And hence are there any ways in which the os.environ['ITEM'] will clears the itemsList if it is not part of the `category`? 
I am looking to see if there are any other in-house codes that will reads the list of items other than using the `os.environ` method (which is the only one I know of...)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've got a module `ezygate`, which you've made in-house. Create a `dict` of `list`s in that module, with the following structure:

```
cats = {'Shirt': ['v-neck', 'round', 'long sleeve']}
```

So long as the other ui can `import ezygate`, you can access the same `dict` there, instead of relying on `os.environ`

```
ezygate.cats['Shirt']
```

`os.environ` is a dictionary stored in the `os` module, but there's no reason you couldn't rely on another dictionary from another module. Depending on your modules, one may jump out more than `ezygate`, but the important thing is that the module be imported wherever you need to rely on the `dict`.

Comment: I think this is definitely the direction OP should go.  Its a Bad Idea (tm) to mess with os.environ mid-session, particularly for passing info between modules.